# Overriding in Java/Android (class -> anonymous class) doesn't work.. why?

Tags: java, android

I've a simple inheritance problem.. but I can't solve it.

This is the basic class:

```
public abstract class RpcOkCallback extends RpcTupleCallback
{
    // [...] constructor [...]

    public boolean callback(int responseCode, final String module, boolean flag){
        if (flag){
            return onResponse(responseCode, module);
        } else {
            return onError(responseCode, module);
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected abstract boolean onResponse(int responseCode, String module);

    protected boolean onError(int responseCode, String module){
        return true;
    }
}
```

And this is an anonymous class that redefine the base class:

```
new RpcOkCallback("color_seek_ir", "set_flash_ir"){
        @Override
        protected boolean onResponse(int responseCode, String module) {
            if (seekBar != null) seekBar.setEnabled(true);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean onError(int responseCode, String module) {
            if (seekBar != null) seekBar.setEnabled(true);
            return true;
        }

    }
```

The question is.. why when the onResponse method is called it calls correctly the overridden method while when it calls the onError method, it calls the base case (the "return true" method)? I've tried to declare abstract the "return error" method too and it works... but I don't want to declare in every anonym class a basic method like that.

Any idea? Thanks :)

Comment: declare onError() method in superclass as abstract

Comment: @Shine: That shouldn't be necessary... and would defeat the point of having a default implementation.

Comment: yes but in most of the cases "return true" is enough.. am I obliged to make it abstract? Why? Shouldn't it be overridden? :(

Comment: when you're instantiating RpcOkCallback, What is the type of assigned variable? RpcOkCallback or RpcTupleCallback ?

Comment: This does look bizarre. Can you log `getClass()` within the `onError` method in `RpcOkCallback`?

Comment: @Shine: Again, that shouldn't matter - that's the whole point of overriding methods...

Comment: Forgive the silly question, but how do you know your override isn't being called?

Comment: ok now I try, thanks! :) @Andy: because the seekbar is still disabled :(

Comment: @JonSkeet it will show RpcTupleCallback. IMHO he's declaring the abstract variable so that override isn't called

Comment: @Shine: No, it won't. It will show `SomeClass$methodName1` or something like that. Calling `getClass()` on an object will *never* return an abstract class. The type of the variable is completely irrelevant - I think you need to read up more on how overriding works.

Comment: @Jon: getClass() I don't know why, but getClass() prints out the Fragment where I define the anonymous class

Comment: @JonSkeet you're night i was confused by static methods

Comment: @filnik: It should print out that fragment *plus something after a dollar* to indicate the anonymous inner class. Are you able to look at all of this in the debugger? If not, add logging to *all* the methods involved. Are you sure the problem isn't just that `seekBar` is null, for example?

Comment: the output is: class com.mycompany.fragment.FragmentName$3 what should I do with the 3? :)

Comment: Did you add the logging in the base abstract class or the anonymous implementation class? As @JonSkeet suggested, the `seekBar` variable may be null. Use a debugger and breakpoints instead of just guessing what's happening.

Comment: I've used a debugger with breakpoints to be sure bro :) it enters the base block, checked.

Comment: OK, can you share a sample application that can reproduce this behavior?

Comment: Also, have you tried making the base method abstract, and seeing if it works properly in that case?

Comment: yes with the abstract method it works properly. Regarding the example I'm trying but it actually works correctly ahah no words

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It actually works correctly (the overriding part), but the callback was already handled by another "onError" method (not overridden) and because of the "return true" the event was canceled before reaching the final destination :(

Adding the abstract and defining all the methods did the job, so thanks corsair (if you want to add your answer or what I will mark as solved the question by you :) ).

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought, that there was some place you weren't overriding it. No need for me to write another answer, feel free to accept your own :)